# Meteor restrict CRUD operations to admins or the document owner

Tags: javascript, mongodb, security, meteor, permissions

Currently in my meteor app I want to be able to restrict database CRUD operations to only document owners, or for example if they have the admin permission.

I am using the meteor alanning:roles package, could someone please explain how I could best leverage this package for restricting who can create, read or update documents based on their roles, or if they are the owner of the document?

Comment: I just made this [DEMO](http://leaderboard-roles.meteor.com) using the Leadboard meteor example but with Roles, check it here is the [Source Code](https://github.com/Ethaan/leadboard-roles)

Comment: did you still have problem with this?

Comment: Not anymore, but the demo site was a huge help thanks c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `alanning:roles` package you can use the `Roles.userIsInRole(userId,role)` where userId and role is an String.

So you can do the following.

```
Posts.allow({
  update:function(){
     var currentUser = Meteor.user(),
         isUserAdmin = Roles.userIsInRole(currentUser,'Admin');
      if(isUserAdmin){
         console.log("Ok the user is logged in on an admin account, lets allow it to update")
         return true;
      }else{
        console.log("Someone just try to update the document and he isn't logged in into an admin account")
        return false;
    }
  }
})
```

Also if you want to double check if the user is `admin` or the `owner` of the document just use the `||` or operator.

```
if(isUserAdmin || doc.userId === userId){return true;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This little code snippet is borrowed from http://discovermeteor.com. It should throw some light on the matter.

```
 ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) {
      return doc && doc.userId === userId;
 };

 Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

 Posts.allow({  
      update: ownsDocument         
 });
```

Because I havent worked with roles package, I cant help. But after a quick look on the github page it looks pretty straightforward.